# Spring Webflux : How to dynamically load caches

Tags: spring-webflux, reactive-programming, project-reactor

I have a use case where I have a spring reactive project. There in the kafka consumer, I load the SSL files location after dynamically creating it.

So, once the truststore, keystore files are created every other time in the kafka consumer and producer same location is to be used.

But my problem is how to do it in a reactive way, because only way I can see is first time it gets created and the `SslConfigFilesLocations` object is populated with locations and every other time same is passed. But the first time operation is synchronous.

And had to use synchronous block which doesn't feel right in a reactive project. So what other solutions are there?

My code :

//starting kafka consumer

```
    @EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
public void initialiseConsumers() {
    consumers = Arrays.asList(new InputEventConsumer[kafkaConfig.getConsumersCount()]);
    IntStream.range(0, kafkaConfig.getConsumersCount()).forEach(i -> {
        consumers.set(i, applicationContext.getBean(InputEventConsumer.class));
        consumers.get(i).setConsumerIndex(i);
        consumers.get(i).setInputEventReceiver(kafkaConfig.inputEventReceiver());
        consumers.get(i).consumeMessage();
    });
}

    @Bean
@Scope(scopeName = ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
public KafkaReceiver<String, String> inputEventReceiver() {
    ReceiverOptions<String, String> receiverOptions = ReceiverOptions.<String, String>create(inputEventConsumerConfigs())
            .subscription(Collections.singleton(TOPIC))
            .addAssignListener(partitions -> log.info("onPartitionsAssigned {}", partitions))
            .addRevokeListener(partitions -> log.info("onPartitionsRevoked {}", partitions));

    return KafkaReceiver.create(receiverOptions);
}


private Map<String, Object> inputEventConsumerConfigs() {
    Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();

    SslConfigFilesLocations sslConfigFilesLocations = configHelper.getSslConfigFilesLocations();

    sslConfigFilesLocations.getTruststorePath().ifPresent(path ->
                props.put(SslConfigs.SSL_TRUSTSTORE_LOCATION_CONFIG, path.toAbsolutePath().toString()));
                
    //other properties added
    return props;
}
```

Now, the configHelper is where I have the synchronous code something like this :

```
public class ConfigHelper {     

private SslConfigFilesLocations sslConfigFilesLocations;

public SslConfigFilesLocations getSslConfigFilesLocations() {
        if (sslConfigFilesLocations == null) {
            generateSSLFiles();
        }
        return sslConfigFilesLocations;
    }

private synchronized void generateSSLFiles() {
    if (sslConfigFilesLocations != null) {
        return;
    }
    Config.SslProperties properties = config.getKafka().getSsl();
    sslConfigFilesLocations = configureSslFiles(properties, encryptionKey); //method which creates files
    log.info("sslConfigFilesLocations " + sslConfigFilesLocations);
}
}
```

And the more reason to have this in the synchronous block was because not just consumer, but even for the producer during the time of bean creation the file locations is getting injected in similar manner as above.

But since I have to just use the same file once created above code I am using. So what would be the best way to do the same thing above?